# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't insert parenthesis?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've been using VS 2015 with no issues. I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, but I'm having this issue:

[image]

I have "Automatic brace completion" enabled. However when I select a Method in intellisense, it does not include parenthesis. How can I fix this? I've tried resetting my settings to default, too.